# How to differentiate code based on iOS version during compile time

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios, ios9

I have been using 'UIKit.UIUserInterfaceStyle UIKit.UITraitCollection::get_UserInterfaceStyle()' API for iOS version 12+. I need to compile the source on iOS version version 9+, I need to differentiate the usage of above API using Conditional compilation. Is there any possibilities to get it done.

Comment: Your are aware that if you decide this a compilation time the resulting app will only run on the iOS version defined at compile time.

Comment: Hi rckoenes,  I can't get your point

Comment: What I mean is, that you should detect this at runtime not compile time. Since at compile time you have no knowledge about the device your code will run on.

Answer (score 0):

You can check the device version at runtime and choose whether to use the APi or not:

```
if (UIDevice.CurrentDevice.CheckSystemVersion(12, 0))
{
    //use api in iOS 12
}
else
{
    //...
}
```